# DataAnnotation DisplayFormat for decimal numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've got his code.
PartialView.

```
<div class="input width110">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Price, @Html.Attributes(@class: "right_text_align", @disabled: "true", @id: "Price"))
</div>
```

Model.

```
public class ServiceModel
{
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SetService(ServiceModel model, string action)
{

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               /*Does smthg.*/
               ModelState.Clear(); 
            }

       return View("Index", rcpModel); 
       //Index is main view, which holds partialView
       //rcpModel holds, model
 }
```

When view loads Decimal is displayed in format "0.00". But after post when modelState is invalid number in displayed in format "0.0000". If model state isvalid, everything goes well. Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Comment: Are you adding anything else to the value? if you have a javascript plugin that adds commas then the default binder won't work

Comment: yes @amhed, I use jQuery Globalize, because my native format is "0,00". Later i try to verify if it's really binder problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have javascript modifying the values on textboxes (currency formatting or commas) then you might be getting binding errors because it will behave as a string. Try this:

**Create a BindingProperty for decimal values**

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

**On your global.asax app_start or WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod add an entry to register the custom binder:**

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 0):

To display dot instead of comma is enough to change the culture to english in every point of the code which is used before the view is called.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("En");
```